# Lookup Error: unknown encoding from robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have two list, `@{results}` and `@{platformversions}`

```
@{results} = [['AAAA', 'BBBB']]
@{platformversions} = [['7.0', '8.0']]
```

I want to append them into a file as shown below.

- AAAA BBBB
- 7.0 8.0

**My attempts**

```
*** Test Cases ***

#Ommitted not useful codes

Write output in file
    Write output in file    @{results} 
    #Add new line to separate results 
    #Write output in file    ${\n}
    Write output in file    @{platformversions}

*** Keywords ***
Write output in file
    [Arguments]     @{output}
    Append To File     ${EXECDIR}/file.txt     @{output}
```

However, i am receiving this error unknown encoding for BBBB and 8.0.

It seems that i have issues appending the list?

Would appreciate if anyone can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@{results}` and `@{platformversions}` are a list of lists. if you are sure that the data you need will be in the first list elements of `@{results}` and `@{platformversions}` respectively then make those as individual lists.

Then run the elements of the lists through a `FOR` loop and write it in the file.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Write output to file
    Write output in file    @{results} 
    Go to new line
    Write output in file    @{platformversions}

*** Keywords ***
Write output in file
[Arguments]     @{output}
    FOR  ${value}  IN  @{output}
        Append To File     ${EXECDIR}/file.txt     ${value} \t
    END

Go to new line
    Append To File     ${EXECDIR}/file.txt    \n
```

This will result in the following  output:

```
AAAA    BBBB
7.0     8.0
```